# rm -r command not working inside of shell in macos catalina

Tags: bash, shell, macos-catalina, rm

I am new to shell scripting. I wrote basic simple.sh file on mac. I put my .sh file to /usr/local/bin directory and I added sh file to the chrometab so as to run every minute. My sh file works fine on standalone terminal screen but I can't delete the folder I want on crometab. Could you please help me? What's my problem? I tried to crontab -e, sudo crontab -e but I can't delete folder I want.

os: macOs Catalina 10.15.7

```
#! /bin/bash

downloadsDirectoryPath="/Users/Odin/Downloads/"
sampleFolderPath=$downloadsDirectoryPath"sampleFolder"
logFilePath=$downloadsDirectoryPath"log.txt"

sudo rm -rf $sampleFolderPath # this row not works, why???
echo "this row absolutely works" >> $logFilePath
```

Comment: Add the exact error message to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Chakra There's no need to make those changes. It's clear what the variables are set to.

Comment: What happens if you do `ls -l /Users/zed/Downloads/sampleFolder` and then `rm -fr  /Users/zed/Downloads/sampleFolder`? (From command-line!)

Comment: You might be running into TCC (Transparency Consent and Control) restrictions, and need to grant Full Disk Access to `cron` (see [this Ask Different Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402132/cronjobs-do-not-run)).

Comment: @zkoza I wrote this command to the terminal screen `ls -l /Users/zed/Downloads/sampleFolder` the result is ' total 197728
-rw-r--r--@ 1 zed  staff  95277923 Jan 14 22:47 VSCode-darwin.zip'

Comment: @GordonDavisson thank you so much. I just allow full disk access permission to the cron and crontab. my simple sh works fine right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with allow full disk access permission to the cron and crontab. Thanks for help @GordonDavisson

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have the permissions to remove the folder.

Likely you can try adding `sudo` before your command like this

`sudo rm -rf $sampleFolderPath`

Else you can just set the folder permissions using `chmod 755 -R foldername`

Comment: Hi, I tried 'sudo rm -rf $sampleFolderPath' as you say but not works on my local machine

Comment: Thats unusual. check if the script is the calling the `absolute path` of the folder you want to remove like  this `\etc\bin\somethingspecific` chances are that its calling a relative path and having trouble finding it. i would highly recommend you to type in the your terminal and test it before putting it into your script!